# Is scripts' use of a shebang line differing from the default shell cause for concern?

Tags: bash, ksh, shebang

my scripts are developed using a shebang line as "#!/bin/ksh" and the default shell is 
`$ echo $SHELL
/bin/ksh`

i am moving all these scripts without changing the shebang line to a new machine where the default shell is 
`$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash`

Should i worry about this ?

I am guessing there should not be any issue as the shebang line will override the interpreter and use ksh as defined in the scripts and as i want it to be.

Please share your thoughts ..

Comment: You're correct: The shebang line is honored on any `execve()` call. Only if your scripts are sourced do you need to care which interpreter they're called from.

Comment: Or  if the listed interpreter doesn't exist or isn't executable or other oddity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default shell does not affect how scripts are executed (unless you're using a shell that does something very strange).

<strike>An executable script with no `#!` line will be executed with `/bin/sh`.</strike> Actually that doesn't appear to be correct, but in any case you don't have to worry about that.

As long as your scripts start with `#!/bin/ksh` *and* you execute them normally, the system will execute them by passing them to `/bin/ksh`.

One thing you *might* have to worry about is whether `/bin/ksh` exists, and if it does, just what it is. On my system (Linux Mint 17), `/bin/ksh` is a symlink to `/etc/alternatives/ksh`, which in turn is a symlink to `/bin/ksh93`.

Scripts with `#!/bin/ksh` are probably common enough that almost all UNIX-like systems will cater to them, and will install *something* that behaves like ksh at that location.

Note that what you call the "default shell", specified by `$SHELL`, is not a system-wide default. It's just the value of a particular environment variable. That variable is set *for each user* on login based on the shell specified in `/etc/passwd` or equivalent; thus different users can have different default shells. You can change the value of `$SHELL` after logging in. The entry in `/etc/passwd` or equivalent is set when the account is created, and can be changed later. Most systems have a default user shell that's set for new accounts if no shell is specified (for example, most Linux systems user `/bin/bash`).

Comment: A script with no `#!` will be executed with `/bin/sh` by zsh and dash, but with the current shell by ksh, bash and ash.

Comment: @thatotherguy: Interesting, thanks for the correction. Of course if you always use `#!` you don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

The supposition given is correct: The shebang line is honored on any `execve()` call. Only if your scripts are sourced (`. yourscript` or `source yourscript`) or lack a valid shebang do you need to care which interpreter they're called from.

If this were not true, scripts in non-shell languages wouldn't work as expected (as the Python interpreter, for instance, is *never* a system's default shell).

Answer (score 0):

The kernel will use the shebang line to select the appropriate interpreter to use when the script is executed in the default manner, whether it is `sh`, `bash`, `ksh`, `expect`, `python`, or whatever. The only real issue to be wary of is scripts written on a system where `sh` is one specific shell (e.g. bash) that are then moved to another system where `sh` is a different shell (e.g. dash) since they may use shell features found in the former that do not exist in the latter.